# android cast for windows with 30fps using usb?

Tags: screen, screen-sharing

I am looking for a free solution that can cast **(mirroring)**
 to windows pc using usb so i can debug on my android phone but i don't have to use my phone to see the app
like this one https://github.com/yangh/sevensquare

Comment: Is Vysor good enough? You don't even need USB - it can stream over ADB Wireless.

Comment: i am looking for free software , visor is not free and also its not good with speed its around 7fps

Comment: Vysor _is_ free at the minimum resolution; also in my experience it may not be 30FPS but could certainly reach 20 over USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading this app called "[AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)" from Play Store.

It has a feature called "AirMirror" which lets you mirror your phone screen over WiFi(root required) or USB(no root needed).

I've been using it for a few years and it's pretty stable.

Comment: its not free , is their any free app you can recommend

Comment: this app requires a ton of permissions. is it normal?